# How to find the lowest value of a set of records in column A based on particular values in Column B?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns in a data frame containing more than 1000 rows. Column A can take values X,Y,None. Column B contains random numbers from 50 to 100.

Every time there is a non 'None' occurrence in Column A, it is considered as occurrence4. so, previous non None occurrence in Column A will be occurrence3, and the previous to that will be occurrence2 and the previous to that will be occurrence1. I want to find the minimum value of column B between occurrence4 and occurrence3 and check if it is greater than the minimum value of column B between occurrence2 and occurrence1. The results can be stored in a new column in the data frame as "YES" or "NO".

Sample Input 
[image]

For example, I need to find the minimum value of Column B between ROWNUM 14 and ROWNUM 11 and compare it with the minimum value of Column B between ROWNUM 6 and ROWNUM 3. Next I need to compare the minimum value between ROWNUM 22 AND ROWNUM 14 and compare it with the minimum value between ROWNUM 11 and ROWNNUM 6.

UPDATE:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0]]*100, columns=list('AB'), index=range(1, 101))
df.loc[[3, 6, 11, 14, 22, 26, 38, 51, 64, 69, 78, 90, 98], 'A'] = 1
df['B'] = np.random.randint(50, 100, size=len(df))
df['result'] = df.loc[df['A'] != 0, 'B'].rolling(4).apply(
    lambda x: x[-2:].min() > x[:2].min(), raw=True)
print(df)
df.to_excel("rollingwindow.xlsx",sheet_name="example")
```

a_guest, I used your code and the output is as follows.

[image]

The minimum value between row 22 and row 14 is 56 which is greater than the minimum value between row 11 and 6 which is 54. So, result must be 1 but your code generates 0.

Comment: Please give **copyable** data instead of an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a sliding window to perform the comparison:

```
result = df.loc[df['A'] != 0, 'B'].rolling(4).apply(
    lambda x: x[-2:].min() > x[:2].min(), raw=True)
```

If the non-zero items should not be compared directly but instead their locations should serve as boundaries for the particular ranges then you can use this modification:

```
result = df.index[df['A'] != 0].to_series().rolling(4).apply(
    lambda x: df.loc[x[2]:x[3], 'B'].min() > df.loc[x[0]:x[1], 'B'].min(), raw=True)
```

For reference, here's the example data frame (using `0` for `None` and `1` otherwise, but the principle is the same):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0]]*24, columns=list('AB'), index=range(1, 25))
df.loc[[3, 6, 11, 14, 22], 'A'] = 1
df['B'] = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=len(df))
print(df)
```

Which looks as follows:

```
    A   B
1   0  98
2   0  99
3   1  73
4   0  42
5   0  76
6   1  80
7   0  91
8   0  40
9   0  15
10  0  51
11  1  93
12  0  82
13  0  73
14  1  86
15  0  71
16  0  84
17  0  62
18  0  20
19  0  53
20  0  12
21  0  68
22  1  97
23  0  74
24  0  51
```

Comment: Hi, I have added an update to my question. Could you pls look at it?

Comment: The minimum value between row 22 and row 14 is 56 which is greater than the minimum value between row 11 and 6 which is 54. So, result must be 1 but your code generates 0.

Comment: @Kartick Now I see what you mean, please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly. Is there a place where I can learn these functions and see more such problems/examples?

Comment: @Kartick Well I'd say Stackoverflow is the place, just watch [the pandas tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas). Of course there are also [tutorials](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/tutorials.html) and for example [this cookbook](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/cookbook.html#cookbook) with lots of recipes. Maybe there you'll find further information.

Comment: can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59076802/finding-minimum-value-of-a-column-between-two-entries-in-another-column